# Removing/modifying LDAP objectclasses/attributes using olc

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm having trouble using openldap's olc to modify a schema without shutting down the server. To test some things out, I made the following schema:

```
objectIdentifier tests        orgUlyssisOID:4
objectIdentifier testAttribute    tests:1
objectIdentifier testObjectClass  tests:2

attributeType ( testAttribute:1 NAME 'attr1'
        DESC 'attribuut 1'
        SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40' )

attributeType ( testAttribute:2 NAME 'attr2'
        DESC 'attribuut 2'
        SUP userPassword
        SINGLE-VALUE )

objectclass ( testObjectClass:1 NAME 'class1'
    DESC 'objectclass 1'
    SUP top
    STRUCTURAL 
    MUST (attr1 $ attr2 ) )
```

And added it to a new schema called test. (cn={9}test.ldif in cn=schema).
Now I can't seem to figure out how to delete *class1* from that schema.
I use the following LDIF (and tried lots of variations too, to no avail)

```
dn : cn={9}test,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcObjectClasses 
olcObjectClasses: ( testObjectClass:1 NAME 'class1' DESC 'objectclass 1' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( attr1 $ attr2 ) )
```

Running *ldapmodify -x -W -D cn=admin,cn=config -f test.ldif -d 0* gives no output. *-d 1* gives this:

```
ldap_create
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:389
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_flush2: 38 bytes to sd 4
ldap_result ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 Connections:
* host: localhost  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Mon Sep 10 11:29:57 2012


** ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 12 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1 message type bind
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x7f2a8ccf3430 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_send_unbind
ber_flush2: 7 bytes to sd 4
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

So no real indication of an error. Where am I doing it wrong?
Bonus question: If I have some entries of a certain objectclass, can I modify it (add/remove attributeTypes) without removing the entries?

Thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be able to remove any schema entry that isn't in use, but I haven't tried it. This answer covers the bonus question. 'slapd -d something' might illuminate what's going on with the first question.